# How can I add a png file in tkinter with no background

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I add no background png image in tkinter, because when I add the image, it gives a white background to the image that I have inserted.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
root = Tk()
root.title("7 Evelyn")
root.geometry('1600x900')

# background image
image_0 = Image.open("C:\\Users\\cerbi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FoodCartRes\\Background-01.png").resize((1600, 900))
bck_end = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_0)
lbl = Label(root, image=bck_end)
lbl.place(y=0, x=0)

# pick a stand
Label(root, text="Choose a Stand", font=('Century Gothic', 30, "bold")).place(y=80, x=600)

# Stands
# Fruit stand
fruit_stand_image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\cerbi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FoodCartRes\\FruitStand\\fruitstand-01.png")
fruit_stand = ImageTk.PhotoImage(fruit_stand_image.resize((400, 500)))
lbl = Label(root, image=fruit_stand)
lbl.place(y=200, x=175)
```

Comment: tkinter widgets ndo not support transparent background.  Use `Canvas` to show the images and text with transparency.

Comment: Tkinter widgets are always opaque rectangles.  The only possible way a transparent image can overlay another image is if they're both drawing items on the same Canvas.